# Moving from MS Access to SQL Server 2012, need help with column history

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm moving an access database from all the data being in MS Access to MS Access being just a frontend, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to do a sort of column history.

I have a `tasks.description` column, and in another table `descriptionLog`, I have `ID`, `Description`, `DateTime`, and `Task`. `Task` is the `ID` of the task from the `Task` table. I was able to do this using data macros, but I need it to be agnostic from MS Access.

I've read a few guides on change tracking but I'm not sure how to get the data out.

Detail on column history: column history is a functionality of MS Access databases 2007 and up where you can set a memo column to be append only, keeping a log of what was entered or removed from the column.

Comment: Please add more description about what "column history" means to you and how you use that information.

Comment: It sounds like you want to track Inserts/Updates/Deletes to the tasks table, specifically, changes to the description column. The simplest way to do this is to use a DML trigger on the tasks table that will insert into the descriptionlog table any time a change is made to that table/column. Triggers do have downsides. Here's a quick overview: http://www.sql-datatools.com/2015/07/Triggers-SQL-Server.html